# Why was this spam flag declined on a post about Arduinos?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I just got a spam flag declined on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260072/raspberipi-arduino-ethernet-switch Here is the answer I flagged as spam: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185533/3129263

> Our company providing the highest quality and reliable Industry
>   Ethernet switch. For more information,
>   visit:http://www.halleycctv.com/

Following the SO Help Center, I found this on the [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) page:

> Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much. Folks will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem; if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.

To me, it entirely matches the above description. This is not even a link to the fittest product the asker needs, just the website homepage. Was I wrong?

Comment: I'm tempted to flag for Spam **even** after yours being declined. This IS spam.

Comment: I flagged it as spam.

Comment: I _love_ your avatar...

Comment: Error 404: Question not found!! Internet Explorer has stopped working. BLUESCREEN

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yeh gods, I have **no idea** how I managed to decline that one.

The only thing I can think of, given the time stamp on the decline, was a UI hick-up caused by network connectivity loss. I was on the train, and I probably failed to notice another flag I handled didn't quite update the UI the way I expected it to.

I'll review my other actions from around that time to make sure I didn't make more such mistakes.

Sorry everyone, thanks for being diligent!

Comment: No harm done, the post is gone ;) Just stays the declined flag, is it worth something? :)

Comment: @Soma: I cannot un-decline it, sorry. I wouldn't worry about it, your flagging behaviour is otherwise fine.

Comment: Knew that ;) As long as the post got deleted

Comment: Sheesh, noob moderators are the worst :(

Comment: @Will: sheesh, old geezers on the bench outside grumping! *In my day, when I was young....*

Comment: How many people regret voting for Martijn already?

Comment: Wow, the mods are human!  This plus the comments made me giggle far more than it probably should have.....

Comment: Who moderates the modmen? _Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?_

Comment: _Stop! Look and Listen_ ;)

Comment: @DanHanly the community usually does a pretty good job at it. Unless valid complaints get lost in a rant, in which case it might take a little longer.

Comment: He use `random.randint(0, 1)`. It returned 0 so it is False so automaticly sends a reject message. How lucky that random usually returns 1 nowadays...

Answer (score 15):

It's been downvoted to smithereens and as a result of that, delete votes became accessible.

The answer is deleted.

We can only guess as to why the flag was declined. Possibly someone wasn't quite paying attention.

Comment: "*Possibly someone wasn't quite paying attention*" -- Maybe we need tests (just like what we have when reviewing posts) for moderators as well? :)

Comment: How many downvotes did it actually manage to accumulate before being nuked?

Comment: That's irrelevant.